# Using Concepts to create static polymorphic interface

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I've been really confused on the concepts syntax and am having a hard time getting started.

I would like to create a polymorphic interface for two types of operator types: unary and binary and opted to try out the concept feature in c++20.

Not sure if it matters, but I used a CRTP create my unary functor compatible with binary functors, however I would like to get rid of that. Here's what I have so far:

```
template <typename T>
        concept UnaryMatrixOperatable = requires(T _op) {
            _op.template operate(std::unique_ptr<Matrix::Representation>{});
            {_op.template operate() } -> same_as<std::unique_ptr<Matrix::Representation>>;
        };

class ReLU : public UnaryAdapter<ReLU> {

                public:
                    std::unique_ptr<Matrix::Representation> operate(
                        const std::unique_ptr<Matrix::Representation>& m);
            };

            static_assert(UnaryMatrixOperatable<ReLU>);
```

However, I am getting a compilation error, presumably because I am not doing some sort of template specialization for a `const matrix &` type?

```
include/m_algorithms.h:122:13: error: static_assert failed
            static_assert(UnaryMatrixOperatable<ReLU>);
            ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
include/m_algorithms.h:122:27: note: because 'Matrix::Operations::Unary::ReLU' does not satisfy 'UnaryMatrixOperatable'
            static_assert(UnaryMatrixOperatable<ReLU>);
                          ^
include/m_algorithms.h:53:26: note: because '_op.template operate(std::unique_ptr<Matrix::Representation>{})' would be invalid: 'operate' following the 'template' keyword does not refer to a template
            _op.template operate(std::unique_ptr<Matrix::Representation>{});
                         ^
```

Thanks for all the help in advance, this design in my code has been problematic for over a week so I'm determined to find a clean way to fix it! Thanks.

Comment: If you want to have `UnaryMatrixOperator` be anything that has `.operate(std::unique_ptr<Matrix::Representation>)` with return `same_as<std::unique_ptr<Matrix::Representation>>`, then  you can just have `requires (T _op, std::unique_ptr<Matrix::Representation> _rep){ {_op.operate(_rep)} -> same_as<std::unique_ptr<Matrix::Representation>>; }`. Possibly you can replace `_rep` with some `std::declval` stuf

Comment: Great thank you this was able to compile! Now I'm just a bit uncertain about how one last thing. Since I am going to create a graph where each `Node` holds a reference to another node, I am imagining that the node will need to be templated to hold objects that are `UnaryMatrixOperatable` and `BinaryMatrixOperatable`. Is there any strategy to contain such a list of heterogeneous types, or heterogeneous unique_ptrs ? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Concepts are not base classes, and you should not treat concept requirements like base class interfaces. Base classes specify exact function signatures that derived classes must implement.

Concepts specify behavior that must be provided. So you explain what that behavior is.

The behavior you seem to want is that you can pass an rvalue of a unique pointer to an `operate` member function. So... say that.

```
template <typename T>
  concept UnaryMatrixOperatable = requires(T _op, std::unique_ptr<Matrix::Representation> mtx)
  {
    _op.operate(std::move(mtx));
  };
```

There's no need for `template` here because you *do not care* if `operate` is a template function. It's not important in the slightest to your code if any particular `T` happens to implement `operate` as a template function or not. You're going to call it this way, so the user must specify some function interface that can be called a such.

The same goes for the zero-argument version. Though your interface should probably make it much more clear that you're moving from the unique pointer in question:

```
template <typename T>
  concept UnaryMatrixOperatable = requires(T _op, std::unique_ptr<Matrix::Representation> mtx)
  {
    _op.operate(std::move(mtx));
    { std::move(_op).operate() } -> std::same_as<decltype(mtx)>;
  };
```

In any case, the other reason you'll get a compile error is that your interface requires two functions: one that gets called with an object and one that does not. Your `ReLu` class only provides one function that pretends to do both.